# Corona SDK newSwitch - switch.isOn is opposite to the actual state

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have added a switch to the page:

```
local function highlightSwitchPress( event )
    local switch = event.target
    print( "Switch with ID '"..switch.id.."' is on: "..tostring(switch.isOn) ) end

local highlightSwitch = widget.newSwitch(
    {
        x = ccx*1.75,
        y = ch*0.4,
        style = "onOff",
        id = "highlightSwitch",
        onPress = highlightSwitchPress,
        initialSwitchState = true
    }
)
highlightSwitch.xScale, highlightSwitch.yScale = 0.8, 0.8
highlightSwitch:setState( { isOn=true, isAnimated=true, onComplete=changeComplete } )
sceneGroup:insert(highlightSwitch)
```

However I noticed that when I click the switch on (green background) the string that is printed out is:

`Switch with ID 'highlightSwitch' is on: false`

and when I click the switch off (grey background) the string that is printed out is:

`Switch with ID 'highlightSwitch' is on: true`

Why is this opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some reading around I found that is is because the `onPress` variable. the `onPress` triggers before the switch changes.

By using the `onRelease`, the event happens after the switch changes and will report the state you want.

[Is there a glitch with widget.newSwitch?](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/71480-is-there-a-glitch-with-widgetnewswitch/)

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. You may want to know the state of the button before it's switched or you may want to know the state after it's switched. See:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newSwitch.html

Rob